Js LocalStorage variable Not working when hosted
I have this code for a timer that is stored in local storage so we can count time even after tab is closed.
It works perfectly on my pc but when I host it Somehow the count is stuck at 200 days.
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

var time= localStorage.getItem('saved_timer');
if(time == null) {
  localStorage.setItem('saved_timer', saved_timer);
  const saved_timer = (deadline);
  time = saved_timer;
}

deadline=time;
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

When I remove this part of code it works even while hosted. But gets refreshed on every page refresh.
var time= localStorage.getItem('saved_timer');
if(time == null) {
  localStorage.setItem('saved_timer', saved_timer);
  const saved_timer = (deadline);
  time = saved_timer;
}

deadline=time;

I've tried using local storage on other pages and they work perfectly too.

localStorage.setItem('saved_timer', saved_timer); const saved_timer = (deadline); has to be swapped

Can you probably try to store the date as a string rather than a date object on your local storage, I am not sure this is the solution but I had far too many issues when I did that, Also it seems like you reference saved_timer before you set it one line below, you have to first assign and then save saved_timer on local storage.

Are you trying to save the return value from getTimeRemaininginto localStorage? Then you need to use JSON.stringify on the returned object before you save it to the localStorage and JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('saved_timer')) when reading it (ideally with a try/catch around getItem). Otherwise you store an object literal into localStorage which doesn't work as intended.
